# Which availability zone does RDS failover to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a database in RDS and I was wondering where in the dashboard do you see the failover AZ. Under summary I can see the AZ of the instance which I assume is the master but where is the slave located? How do I know which AZ it will fail over to?

Comment: It will be in the other subnet/az defined in your [subnet group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Subnets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subnets in which you launch your multi-az deployment RDS instances determine the availability zones for your master and slave (Primary and secondary) RDNS instances.You can also check the secondary server AZ from the **Replication** section at the bottom of the database configuration details.

If you selected "Do not create a standby instance" at the time of creation of the RDS instance ,then you will not see any secondary RDS instance.

Comment: for those wondering. I found it in Configuration -> Secondary Zone